# Make option not available when it is already chosen

Tags: php

So i have a website where you can reserve spots, but the problem is that you can choose the same spot over and over again, even if it is basically reserved already.
So what i want is, for example, you choose option 1 on wednesday between 10:00 and 12:00, but if someone else also wants to choose option 1 on wednesday between 10:00 and 12:00 they would get an error message saying that the option is already reserved.

Here is some code, maybe it will help:
**This is a foreach to show all the options and their times for when they are available**

```php
$show = new Docent();
        $beschikbaarheden = $show->selecteerOpties();

        foreach ($beschikbaarheden as $beschikbaarheid) {

            echo '<div class="optieContainer">';
            echo '<b>Optie: </b>' . $beschikbaarheid['optieNaam'] . '<br>';
            echo '<b>Beschikbaar: </b><br>' . $beschikbaarheid['optieBegin'] . ' - ' . $beschikbaarheid['optieEind'];
            echo '</div>';
        }
```

**This is the form where you choose the option, time and date:**

```
<form method="POST" class="reserverenFormContainer">
        <input type="text" name="reserverenEmail" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['gebruikerEmail'];?>" hidden>
        <input type="text" name="reserverenNaam" class="reserverenForm readonly" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['gebruikerVoornaam'],"&nbsp;". $_SESSION['gebruikerAchternaam']; ?>" readonly><br>
        <input type="text" name="reserverenKlas" class="reserverenForm readonly" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['gebruikerKlas']; ?>" readonly><br>
        <select name="reserverenOptie">
            <option value="" hidden selected class="reserverenForm select">Optie:</option>
            <?php
                $show = new Reserveringen();
                $opties = $show->selecteerOpties();

                foreach ($opties as $optie) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $optie["optieNaam"] . '">' . $optie["optieType"] . " - " . $optie["optieNaam"] . '</option>';
                }
            ?>
        </select><br>
        <input type="date" name="reserverenDatum" class="reserverenForm reserverenDatum" id="datum"><br>
        <input type="time" name="reserverenBeginTijd" class="reserverenForm reserverenTijd" min="08:30" max="15:45"><br>
        <input type="time" name="reserverenEindTijd" class="reserverenForm reserverenTijd" min="08:45" max="16:00"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="reserveren" class="reserverenForm knop" value="Reserveren"><br>
    </form>
```

**And this is the code behind it so it checks if the form is empty and some other things before it gets send to the database**

```
    if (isset($_POST['reserveren'])) {

        $optie = new Reserveringen();
        $opties = $optie->selecteerOptieType();

        foreach ($opties as $optieTypes) {

            //kijken of de gekozen optie overeen komt met Robotsysteem
            if ($_POST['reserverenOptie'] == $optieTypes["optieType"] . ' - ' . $optieTypes["optieNaam"]) {

                //kijken of op de gekozen dag een docent aanwezig is
                if ($dagen[$heleWeek] > 0) {

                    //nadat er op de knop geklikt is kijken of alles wel is ingevuld
                    if (empty($_POST['reserverenOptie']) || empty($_POST['reserverenDatum']) || empty($_POST['reserverenBeginTijd']) || empty($_POST['reserverenEindTijd'])) {
                        echo 'Niet alles is ingevuld, vul alles in en probeer opnieuw.';
                    } else {
                        $reserverenNaam = $_POST['reserverenNaam'];
                        $reserverenKlas = $_POST['reserverenKlas'];
                        $reserverenEmail = $_POST['reserverenEmail'];
                        $reserverenOptie = $_POST['reserverenOptie'];
                        $reserverenDatum = $_POST['reserverenDatum'];
                        $reserverenBeginTijd = $_POST['reserverenBeginTijd'];
                        $reserverenEindTijd = $_POST['reserverenEindTijd'];

                        $reserveer = new Reserveringen();
                        $reserveer->reserveer($reserverenNaam, $reserverenKlas, $reserverenEmail, $reserverenOptie, $reserverenDatum, $reserverenBeginTijd, $reserverenEindTijd);
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Niemand is aanwezig, probeer een andere dag.');</script>";
                }
            } else {
                $reserverenNaam = $_POST['reserverenNaam'];
                $reserverenKlas = $_POST['reserverenKlas'];
                $reserverenEmail = $_POST['reserverenEmail'];
                $reserverenOptie = $_POST['reserverenOptie'];
                $reserverenDatum = $_POST['reserverenDatum'];
                $reserverenBeginTijd = $_POST['reserverenBeginTijd'];
                $reserverenEindTijd = $_POST['reserverenEindTijd'];

                $reserveer = new Reserveringen();
                $reserveer->reserveer($reserverenNaam, $reserverenKlas, $reserverenEmail, $reserverenOptie, $reserverenDatum, $reserverenBeginTijd, $reserverenEindTijd);
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope this is clear enough and my question is able to be done, if there are questions about my code or you need to see more code, i am happy to help.

Comment: Please explain where exactly your problem lies with achieving this yourself. What have you tried, and how did it fail? (Please note that this site is not a code writing service, where you just drop off what you have and what you want as some kind of “work order”.)

Comment: The problem isn't in the code you show, but in the code you don't show. How does the code *knows* a spot is reserved? When you know that, you can choose to either not show the option or blank it out.

Comment: I have not tried anything yet, because maybe people can help me get started on how it should work. I was thinking of something related to checking the option name together with the time and date it has, but i'm not sure if that would work and how to do that. I also don't know how to put it on inactive or something when the option has been choosen for a specific time and date

Comment: You mean whatever people make a reservation for, is not yet stored anywhere? If that is the case then it sounds like homework.

Comment: When someone makes a reservation and it passed some checkups, if the checkups did not go wrong or not give any errors then it gets send to the database

Comment: `$beschikbaarheden` should be limited to only the available slots, filtering out the slots alreadsy been taken.